# How do use DL as a sender name

Tags: exchange-2010

Hi Can you please help in below scenario

I have DL name "A" created on Exchange 2010. Need to give send as permission to another DL "B". So that DL  "B"  members can send mails using DL "A".
And recipients should get Sender name as DL "A" and also sent by Individual user name as security concern who sent this mail.

Can anyone help me in this...

Answer (score 0):

### To `Send As` a distribution list:

From the AD object for `Distribution List A`, you need to grant `Send As` permissions to the members of `Distribution List B`.  You will basically be going into the security tab of `Distribution List A`, adding `Distribution List B`, and then ticking the `Allow` box beside the `Send As` permission.

[Here's a guide with screenshots](http://exchangeserverpro.com/exchange-2010-send-as-permissions-distribution-group).

**Emails will be received as coming from `Distribution List A`.**

### To `Send on Behalf of` a distribution list:

Again, it's a simple matter of setting the permission for the members of `Distribution List B` on the `Distribution List A` object, though there's no `GUI` option to do this in Exchange, so you'll be using PowerShell.

[Another tutorial from the same guy, with screenshots and code examples](http://exchangeserverpro.com/exchange-2010-grant-send-behalf-permissions-distribution-group).

**Emails will be received as coming from `Sender` on behalf of `Distribution List A`.**